K8s and Linux Audit Logs Missing From Splunk OTEL Collected Logs
I'm migrating from the Splunk Connect for Kubernetes Helm Chart to the SignalFX Splunk Otel Collector Helm Chart. I'm having trouble translating the custom filters that we have in the SCK chart to add metadata and send logs to indexes based on container name.
The custom filters we have on the fluentd section of the values files for SCK are below
    customFilters:
      <truncated>

      # Write each log into the index which matches the namespace's name
      # If a container is marked as containing audit logs, we push it to a dedicated audit index
      IndexNameFilter:
        tag: tail.containers.**
        type: jq_transformer
        body: |
          jq 'if .record.container_name|startswith("audit") then .record.splunk_index = ("audit-" + .record.namespace) | .record else .record.splunk_index = .record.namespace | .record end'


      # Write k8s audit logs to its own index
      K8sAuditIndexNameFilter:
        tag: tail.file.kube:apiserver-audit
        type: jq_transformer
        body: |
          jq '.record.splunk_index = "audit-kube" | .record'

Looking at the example values file and the logs only example I've translated that to the Otel chart with the transform processor
 agent:
    enabled: true
    config:
      processors:
        <truncated>
        transform/namespace_to_index:
          error_mode: ignore
          log_statements:
            - context: log
              statements:
                - set(resource.attributes["com.splunk.index"], Concat(["audit", resource.attributes["k8s.namespace.name"]], "-")) where IsMatch(resource.attributes["k8s.container.name"], "audit-.*")
                - set(resource.attributes["com.splunk.index"], resource.attributes["k8s.namespace.name"])

The transform/namespace_to_index is included in service.pipeline.logs.processors, and the logsCollection.extraFileLogs are set up to watch the audit files which I have triple checked exist in the expected places
extraFileLogs:
      filelog/kube-audit: # sck logs go to audit-kube index, but got it in otel index for now.
        include: 
          - /var/log/kubernetes/audit/kube-apiserver-audit*.log
        start_at: beginning
        include_file_path: true
        include_file_name: false
        resource:
          host.name: resource["k8s.node.name"]
          com.splunk.index: audit-kube
          com.splunk.sourcetype: kube:apiserver-audit
          com.splunk.source: /var/log/kubernetes/audit/kube-apiserver-audit.log
      filelog/linux-audit:
        include:
          - /var/log/audit/audit*.log
        start_at: beginning
        include_file_path: true
        include_file_name: false
        resource:
          host.name: resource["k8s.node.name"]
          com.splunk.index: audit-linux
          com.splunk.sourcetype: linux:audit
          com.splunk.source: /var/log/audit/audit.log

However the pod logs show that the collector cannot find the audit files
2024-05-16T14:23:44.206Z   warn    fileconsumer/file.go:132    finding files: no files match the configured criteria   {"kind": "receiver", "name": "filelog/kube-audit", "data_type": "logs", "component": "fileconsumer"}
Here is the entire values file for the Splunk Otel Collector
---
splunk-otel-collector:
  clusterName: ${env:CLUSTER_NAME}
  priorityClassName: "system-cluster-critical"
  splunkPlatform:
    # sets Splunk Platform as a destination. Use the /services/collector/event
    # endpoint for proper extraction of fields.
    endpoint: "https://our_endpoint.splunkcloud.com:443/services/collector/event"
    token: "fake-placeholder-token"
    index: "k8s" # should be able to replace with "" to dynamically set index as was done with SCK
    logsEnabled: true
  secret:
    create: false
    name: splunk-otel-credentials
    validateSecret: false
  logsCollection:
    containers:
      enabled: true
      excludePaths:
        - /var/log/containers/*fluent-bit*
        - /var/log/containers/*speaker*
        - /var/log/containers/*datadog*
        - /var/log/containers/*collectd*
        - /var/log/containers/*rook-ceph*
        - /var/log/containers/*bird*
        - /var/log/containers/*logdna*
        - /var/log/containers/*6c6f616462616c2d*
        - /var/log/containers/*lb-6c6f616462616c2d*
      # extraOperators:
      #   - type: copy
      #   # Copy the name of the namespace associated with the log record.
      #     from: resource["k8s.namespace.name"]
      #   # Copy to the index key, so the record will be ingested under the index named after the k8s namespace.
      #     to: resource["com.splunk.index"]    
    extraFileLogs:
      filelog/kube-audit: # sck logs go to audit-kube index, but got it in otel index for now.
        include: 
          - /var/log/kubernetes/audit/kube-apiserver-audit*.log
        start_at: beginning
        include_file_path: true
        include_file_name: false
        resource:
          host.name: resource["k8s.node.name"]
          com.splunk.index: audit-kube
          com.splunk.sourcetype: kube:apiserver-audit
          com.splunk.source: /var/log/kubernetes/audit/kube-apiserver-audit.log
      filelog/linux-audit:
        include:
          - /var/log/audit/audit*.log
        start_at: beginning
        include_file_path: true
        include_file_name: false
        resource:
          host.name: resource["k8s.node.name"]
          com.splunk.index: audit-linux
          com.splunk.sourcetype: linux:audit
          com.splunk.source: /var/log/audit/audit.log # can't find these results for SCK yet
  extraAttributes:
    fromLabels:
      - key: k8s.pod.labels.cluster.name
        tag_name: cluster_name
        from: pod
      - key: k8s.namespace.labels.cluster.class
        tag_name: cluster_class
        from: namespace
      - key: k8s.namespace.labels.cluster.env
        from: namespace
      - key: k8s.node.name
        tag_name: host
        from: node
  agent:
    enabled: true
    config:
      processors:
        # add cluster metadata to each logged event
        # these are pulled in as environment variables due to a limitation
        # as helm is unable to use templating when specifying values.
        attributes/cluster_name_filter:
          actions:
            - key: cluster_name
              action: upsert
              value: ${env:CLUSTER_NAME}
        attributes/cluster_class_filter:
          actions:
            - key: cluster_class
              action: upsert
              value: ${env:CLUSTER_CLASS}
        attributes/cluster_env_filter:
          actions:
            - key: cluster_env
              action: upsert
              value: ${env:CLUSTER_ENV}
        transform/namespace_to_index:
          error_mode: ignore
          log_statements:
            - context: log
              statements:
                - set(resource.attributes["com.splunk.index"], Concat(["audit", resource.attributes["k8s.namespace.name"]], "-")) where IsMatch(resource.attributes["k8s.container.name"], "audit-.*")
                - set(resource.attributes["com.splunk.index"], resource.attributes["k8s.namespace.name"])
        # attributes/namespace_filter:
        #   actions:
        #     - key: com.splunk.index
        #       action: upsert
        #       value: k8s.namespace.name
        #     - key: logindex
        #       action: delete
      exporters:
        debug:
          verbosity: detailed
      service:
        pipelines:
          logs:
            processors:
              - memory_limiter
              - k8sattributes
              - filter/logs
              - batch
              - resourcedetection
              - resource
              - resource/logs
              - attributes/cluster_name_filter
              - attributes/cluster_class_filter
              - attributes/cluster_env_filter
              - transform/namespace_to_index
            #   - attributes/namespace_filter
            receivers:
              kubeletstats:
                metric_groups:
                  - node
                  - pod
                  - container
              filelog:
                include:
                  - /var/log/pods/*/*/*.log
                  - /var/log/kubernetes/audit/*.log
                  - /var/log/audit/audit*.log
                start_at: beginning
                include_file_name: false 
                include_file_path: true
                operators:
                  # parse cri-o format
                  - type: regex_parser
                    id: parser-crio
                    regex:
                      '^(?P<time>[^ Z]+) (?P<stream>stdout|stderr) (?P<logtag>[^ ]*)
                      ?(?P<log>.*)$'
                    output: extract_metadata_from_filepath
                    timestamp:
                      parse_from: attributes.time
                      layout_type: gotime
                      layout: '2006-01-02T15:04:05.999999999Z07:00'
                  # Parse CRI-Containerd format
                  - type: regex_parser
                    id: parser-containerd
                    regex:
                      '^(?P<time>[^ ^Z]+Z) (?P<stream>stdout|stderr) (?P<logtag>[^ ]*)
                      ?(?P<log>.*)$'
                    output: extract_metadata_from_filepath
                    timestamp:
                      parse_from: attributes.time
                      layout: '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%LZ'
                  - type: copy
                    from: resource["k8s.namespace.name"]
                    to: resource["com.splunk.index"]
    # Set Environment Variables to be set on every Pod in the DaemonSet
    # Many of these are used as a work-around to include additional log metadata
    # from what is available in `.Values` but inaccessible due to limitations of
    # Helm.
    extraEnvs:
      - name: CLUSTER_NAME
        valueFrom:
          configMapKeyRef:
            name: cluster-info
            key: CLUSTER_NAME
      - name: CLUSTER_CLASS
        valueFrom:
          configMapKeyRef:
            name: cluster-info
            key: CLUSTER_CLASS
      - name: CLUSTER_ENV
        valueFrom:
          configMapKeyRef:
            name: cluster-info
            key: CLUSTER_ENV
    # The container logs may actually be a series of symlinks. In order to read
    # them, all directories need to be accessible by the logging pods. We use
    # volumes and volume mounts to achieve that.
    extraVolumes:
      - name: containerdlogs
        hostPath:
          path: /var/lib/containerd/pod-logs
      - name: podlogs
        hostPath:
          path: /var/log/pods
      - name: varlogcontainers
        hostPath:
          path: /var/log/containers
      - name: kubeauditlogs
        hostPath:
          path: /var/log/kubernetes/audit
      - name: linuxauditlogs
        hostPath:
          path: /var/log/audit
    extraVolumeMounts:
      - name: containerdlogs
        mountPath: /var/lib/containerd/pod-logs
        readOnly: true
      - name: podlogs
        mountPath: /var/log/pods
        readOnly: true
      - name: varlogcontainers
        mountPath: /var/log/containers
        readOnly: true
      - name: kubeauditlogs
        mountPath: /var/log/kubernetes/audit
        readOnly: true
      - name: linuxauditlogs
        mountPath: /var/log/audit
        readOnly: true
    resources:
      limits:
        cpu: 1
        memory: 4Gi
      requests:
        cpu: 1
        memory: 1Gi

